# Connecting to existing graphdb is getting failed

Tags: java, neo4j

While trying to connect to the existing or already created neo4j db instance, I am getting the below exception. I thought, this instance was in used in the Graph DB viewer so tried to close it and also tried a restart of entire machine, but nothing works.

API:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-graphdb-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

Code:

```
    dbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
    File dbpath = new File("D:/neo4j/Neo4j1");
    db = dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(dbpath)
            .newGraphDatabase();
    registerShutdownHook(db);
```

Revised Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory, D:\neo4j\Neo4j1
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:144)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory.newFacade(CommunityFacadeFactory.java:40)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:108)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:100)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.lambda$createDatabaseCreator$194(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:89)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$$Lambda$1/1851691492.newDatabase(Unknown Source)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:183)
at com.mycompany.neo4jnative.NewClass.<init>(NewClass.java:55)
at com.mycompany.neo4jnative.NewClass.main(NewClass.java:35)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.Recovery@101b3a78' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:416)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:62)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:98)
at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:508)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:99)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:140)
... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized log entry version -9. At position LogPosition{logVersion=0, byteOffset=2450817} and entry version null
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.entry.LogEntryVersion.byVersion(LogEntryVersion.java:147)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.entry.VersionAwareLogEntryReader.readLogEntry(VersionAwareLogEntryReader.java:83)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.LogEntryCursor.next(LogEntryCursor.java:50)
at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.LatestCheckPointFinder.find(LatestCheckPointFinder.java:77)
at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.PositionToRecoverFrom.apply(PositionToRecoverFrom.java:53)
at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.DefaultRecoverySPI.getPositionToRecoverFrom(DefaultRecoverySPI.java:112)
at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.Recovery.init(Recovery.java:72)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:406)
... 17 more
```

Update:

Steps to recreate the scenario:

1. Create the graph db from java code (using above code).
2. Do what ever manipulation you want like adding, dropping node, create relationship
3. Stop the java instance and open the db in Neo4j community viewer tool
4. Follow the password setup steps.
5. Query for the nodes
6. Stop the Neo4j community viewer tool
7. Now try to look up the same DB from java code will end up with the exception mentioned above.

Comment: Me too faced the same issue, seems like kernel dependency version is not suitable for this combination. Does any know the workable combination of depencies ?

Comment: Why are the neo versions mixed? 3.0.1 and 3.0.4?

Comment: I also tried with the version 3.0.4 for all the dependencies given above,Eventhough  I am getting the same problem again

Comment: @Luanne , listed out the step to recreate the posted issue

Comment: Is there more of that stacktrace?